# Using Google Channel API with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, channel-api

First post here, my question is simple !

Is there a way to use the Channel API in PHP on Google AppEngine ?

I cannot find the equivalent of [this library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/channel/package-summary) for PHP.

If not, what would be the best alternative ? Learn Java EE ? I'd like something simple and fast, working on GAE.

Thank you for you help !

Comment: It's also available for python just saying. PHP in new to GAE. Ask at irc if there are plans for this. Also the channels api is quite limited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it's still a beta feature. What do you mean by 'ask at irc' ?
If anyone has a simple alternative to Channel API I'd be glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel API is currently not available on PHP. You could write a separate module (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) in Python, Java or Go to handle the Channel API calls in your project.